# Is there a name for the normal CDF function $\Phi(\cdot)$?

Tags: terminology, special-functions, normal-distribution

I can't seem to find a plain English name for the CDF of the normal distribution $\Phi(x)$. However, I am aware of several other related functions that have a name, so I feel like this one should as well.

- The CDF of the logistic distribution $\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}$ is known as the [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function). (It also happens to be sigmoidal like this one.)
- The inverse normal CDF $\Phi^{-1}(x)$ is known as the [probit function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit).

Doesn't this function have a name as well?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$~$N$(0, 1), then the cdf  $\Phi (x)$ is related to the Error Function by:

$\Phi (x) = \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{erf} \left(x/ \sqrt{2}\right)$

For more detail on the error function, see for instance:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: Sorry, but no one will take me seriously if I call $\Phi(x)$ the error function.

Comment: @AndrewMao I don't think that's what he was suggesting. But your function *is* a linear transformation of the error function.

Answer (score 0):

In Russian mathematical literature a similar function is usually called Laplace function. However, the lower limit in the integral is *usually* zero when defining Laplace function.
Note that I've never seen "Laplace function" to be used in English.